# Django database Migration Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: django

i am beginner at Django python. after create the table and run the migration command i got the error was i attached below.what i tried so far i attached below.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Students(models.Model):
    StudentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    StudentName = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Course = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Fee =models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

**Full Error after run the migranation command : python manage.py makemigrations StudentApp**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\django\stud_crud\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\django\stud_crud\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1128, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StudentApp'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huKTV.jpg)

Comment: Share your app directory structure. It seems, that you have "StudentApp" inside `INSTALLED_APPS`, but it cannot find it.

Comment: i add the screen image above please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check two things:

**First:** Check your folder structure. I see the image of your structure but can't judge because I am not familiar with that IDE. Your folder structure should be set up like this:

```
STUD_CRUD/ -stud_crud/
           -students/
           -manage.py
```

**Second:** Check the naming of your apps. It should look like this:

```py
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # [...]
    "students.apps.StudentsConfig",
]
```

Here the "first" students refers to the folder name you gave your app. So `students` is correct; I verified with the image of your project. `StudentsConfig` refers to the class name you gave it in apps.py inside of students folder.

```py
# apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
class StudentsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
    name = "students"
```

Somewhere you have other variable names. I stated an example that should work.

I am almost sure that your mistake is to be found in `STUD_CRUD/students/apps.py`.